# Java Restlet-Client - cannot set credentials for service

Tags: java, restlet

I've created a Java Restlet-Client for an OData WCF-Service with both a `ChallengeScheme` and a `ChallengeResponse`. Now I want to set these credentials for the Webservice I've created with

`String [] arguments = {"URI", "path"};
 Generator.main(arguments);`.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't use the `setauth(credentials)` method for my webservice like so:

```
TestWebService s = new TestWebService();
s.setauth(credentials);
```

It seems the method is not known. So far I've imported these packages:

```
import org.restlet.data.ChallengeResponse;                             
import org.restlet.data.ChallengeScheme;
import org.restlet.ext.odata.Generator;
import org.restlet.ext.odata.Query;
```

and used these Restlet-JARs (most of them have been added because the code wouldn't compile without them):

```
org.restlet.ext.odata.jar
org.restlet.jar
org.restlet.ext.atom.jar
org.restlet.ext.xml.jar
org.freemaker.jar
org.restlet.ext.freemaker.jar
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `s.setauth(credentials)` you can use `setCredentials(credentials)`.